# Border Hover color error On Region of US Map SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, hover

I have US map with states and the regions on Hover in svg

`Here is the link to` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dv4x3fek/)

the problem here is that the stroke hover color of the regions, for example Pacific not working well.

In The **red color highlighted region** the stroke hover color is working good, 
but in **green color highlighted region** the stroke hove color is not working well, it is thinner with mix of white. Please look at the image below to understand what i am trying to say

[Map with error & highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mrXZ.jpg)

I want it be like the the below image, Please look at the image below

[Map Stroke/border Hover required type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz4Rn.jpg)

Please guide me the way to do it.

Comment: show the problem with your code as you can

Comment: @Vishnuprasad Please check my updated question

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: @Paulie_D the body has more than 30,000 characters

Comment: Then you need to find a way to reduce it to **just the part that's giving you problems**.

Comment: @Paulie_D  The SVG has the us map, its obvious that it will have more than 30,000 characters in body due to 100's of path. Please help me on the border hove color issue

Comment: But you are only concerned with **one** path.

Comment: @Vishnuprasad When i hover over text of states the bg color doesn't works, Please guide me to fix it

Comment: @Vishnuprasad Please answer here as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960456/error-while-hover-on-text-svg-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, It may have little bit difficult because of `stroke-width` sizes. Just a look at the below answer, I have made it with hover `fill` color.

```
.region:hover path {
  fill: #dece0c;
}
.st1, .st2, .st3 {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Link to: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgn2d0wy/3/)

Comment: Isn't there any way we can provide border hover color for the regions only?
Please guide me here

Comment: @NimeshDeo don't forget to accept answer if it helps you.. :)

Comment: Thanks it worked but as i wanted the border hover color to be working.
It would be great if you help me on that point.

Comment: Please answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960456/error-while-hover-on-text-svg-map